# $u,v$ are two solutions of differential equation $y'' + Py' + Qy =0,$ with $P$ and $Q$ functions of $x$, then value of $u\frac{dv}{dx}-v\frac{du}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $u$ and $v$ are the two solutions of differential equation $$y'' + Py' + Qy =0,$$ with $P$ and $Q$ functions of $x$, then $$u\frac{dv}{dx}-v\frac{du}{dx}$$
is equal to?

The answer given is $$ae^{-\int Pdx}\,, $$
where $a$ is an arbitrary constant.

I'm familiar with solving second order linear differential equations but I just can't wrap my head around this question. I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W(x) = uv' - vu'$. Show that $W'(x) = -P(x)W(x)$, and thus that $$W = a \exp\left(-\int P \; \mathrm dx\right).$$
$W(x)$ here is the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) of the differential equation, and this result is [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity).